# How to change font in Arista Transcoder?

Tags: subtitle

Arista Transcoder is a great simple tool to burn subtitles into videos but I could not figure out how to change the font and possibly size and background of the subtitle. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you choose add a file: **Resize dialog, on top-right corner click on the gear button**

You can select font name & size, unfortunately no background color option.

For colored subtitle, you can use FFmpeg command line. See [How to Add Font size in subtitles in ffmpeg video filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21363334/how-to-add-font-size-in-subtitles-in-ffmpeg-video-filter)

[image: subtitle font & size selection]

Comment: Oh never noticed that cog! Is there any chance that I can change the font color too?

Comment: @corev, Unfortunately it does not support color setting, you may use ffmpeg I have updated answer.